# Why do I have to manually add Flex libraries in ActionScript Project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

When I create a new ActionScript project in Flash Builder, I have to add standard Flex SDK libraries manually one by one even though I have already included Flex SDK library.
Am I missing some setting, so that compiler is not finding all the SWCs already present in Flex SDK library?

Comment: included Flex SDK library? How?

Comment: @BotMaster The default Flex SDK library automatically gets included in the project build path, but Flash Builder's compiler does not includes its individual SWCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash Builder's new Project wizard, you can create a new "Flex Project" and then select "Desktop" as the application type.
In next screen, it asks for default main class, just specify your main .as (ActionScript) class file here.
This way you won't have to write any MXML code and all the libraries of standard Flex library will be implicitly available for the project files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Flex project instead of an Actionscript project.

On the File menu, choose "New > Other", then expand Flash Builder and choose "Flex Project"

The Flex SDK will be included automatically.

Comment: Why can't we create a simple ActionScript project? The default Flex SDK library automatically gets included in that as well, but the problem is that none of its SWCs are included in the build path.

Comment: @SoSi If you want to use the Flex framework, create a Flex project.  If you want a simple Actionscript project, create one of those.  It sounds like you're trying to shoehorn a Flex project into something it isn't.